# Best way to store large searchable text files

Tags: database, search, large-text, large-data

I am developing an online Bible search program. The Bible is a pretty large book, taking up nearly 5MB of space in plain text. I am planning on implementing an API in the program as well allowing other websites to include their own Bible search widgets and programs without having to develop the search queries or storing Bibles on their own servers.

With this in mind, I am going to expect that eventually I will have a moderate flow of queries passing through the program. Also, for those not familiar with the Bible, it has 2 methods of formatting the text. It can contain both red text and italics. I need a way to store the Scriptures along with the red letter and italics formatting but allowing the search queries to ignore the formatting.

It also needs to be fast and as efficient (memory and cpu usage) as possible. Any storage format will be considered (MySQL, JSON or XML text files, etc) as long as the querying can be done ignoring the formatting. File size and count doesn't really matter, so splitting up the books or even chapters into separate files is fine by me.

One more important thing to keep in mind though, is that I want to have some form of search method that can search across multiple verses. So a search for "*but have everlasting life for God sent not his Son*" would return *John 3:16,17*. Thanks for all ideas!

Comment: you can search really fast using grep. what platform are you planning to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a bunch of different open source document search engines which are made for precisely what you're trying to do.  Solr, Elastic Search, Xapian, Whoosh, Haystack (made for Django) and others.  There are other posts on S.O. and elsewhere that go into the benefits of using one vs another, but your requirements are simple enough that any of them will be more than fine (and easily scale with very minimal effort should your project take off, which is always nice to know).  So look at their examples and see which one looks most intuitive to you - Solr is arguably the most popular and it's the only one I've worked with, but Elastic Search uses the same popular Lucene backend and is apparently much easier to get up and running, so I would start there.

As for the actual implementation, you'll want to index each verse as a separate "document" if the single verse (or just verse number) is what you want to return.  The search engine handles the ranking of the results based on relevancy (usually using a tf/idf algorithm, in case you're interested).

The way I'd handle the italics and red text is to include some kind of markup in the text  (i.e. wrap the phrase in single asterisks for italics, double asterisks for red) and then tell the analyzer to ignore those characters - there may be a simpler way in the framework you end up choosing, though, so take that with a grain of salt.  The queries spanning multiple verses requirement is more complicated, but the answer will probably involve indexing each whole chapter as a document instead of (or maybe in addition to? I'd have to think about it more) each verse.

A word of caution - if you're not familiar with search indexing, even something designed to be plug-and-play like Elastic Search will probably still require some time and effort to set up, so if you absolutely *need* to get this up and running quickly and you're already familiar with MySQL I suppose it could work (it does do fulltext search).  But it's certainly not the best tool for the job, so if this is a project that you're invested in you will thank yourself later if you put in a little bit of work to learn one of these search frameworks.  It may be overkill in terms of the amount of text you're dealing with, as others have pointed out, but it will be extremely flexible in how you can search on that text which seems to be what you want.  For instance, adding other requirements later on would be very straightforward (for instance, you could let people limit their search to only matches in the red text).

Comment: thanks for the answer. is this still the best answer approach in 2020?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know the bible had formatting. What is it used for? If it is for the verses, I'd suggest you store every verse in a database. In a highly normalized form, you got a table with books, a table with chapters and a table with verses. Each verse consists of a verse number and a verse text.

Now, I think the chapters don't have titles so they are actually just a number as well. In that case it it silly to store them separately, so you got just your table of books and a table of verses, in which each verse has a chapter number and a verse number and a verse text. That text I think of to be plain text, isn't it?

If the verse is plain text, you can easily make it searchable by storing it in MySQL and create a FULLTEXT index for it. That way, you can search quite efficiently and even use wildcards and such.

If the verse was to have formatting, you could choose to create two columns, one with the plain text for searching, and one with the formatted text for display, but I doubt you would need this.

PS: 5 MB of text is nothing really. If you got a dedicated program, you could keep it in memory in a single string and use `strpos` or a similar function to find a text. What language, database and platform are you using?

Comment: I am using a LAMP server. I am programming in PHP and MySQL would be the best database to use. Your idea to store a plain text version and formatted version would work great. I never thought to do that. The "formatting" I am talking about are the words of Christ in red and the italicized words in the King James Version.